# Javascript, array item undefined. Pushed using Reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, push, reduce

So I'm trying to get the name of array items shown on web.
This is "modelscount" array in which objects look like:

```
[{"model":"1","count":4},{"model":"2","count":2}...]
```

Model here displays number, but instead of number `i` have to show models name that `i` get from other array of objects.
This is "models" array in which object looks like that:

```
[
  { 
    "_id":"611647e62001fe0ff0af0ad6",
    "model":"1",
    "name":"FIAT 500",
    "hour_price":4.2,
    "__v":0
  },
  { 
    "_id":"61165c7e8fecf33528790b45",
    "model":"2",
    "name":"BMW X4",
    "hour_price":6.9,
    "__v":0
  }
].
```

So `i` figured I will take the name from each object with reduce method, then create array that checks number of arrays item which corresponds with model in each item of "modelscount" array. It all looked good on paper, but when i try to get an item from array with names some why I get undefined?
How can I fix that?
Can you suggest other solution for this problem?
Here is the problem as seen from console:[as seen in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXXyy.png)

```js
const showModelsCount = () => {
  let arrayOfModels = [];
  fetch(MODELS_URI)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('this is data', data);
      data.reduce((total, item) => {
        arrayOfModels.push(item.name);
        return arrayOfModels; 
      }, '');
      arrayOfModels;
    });
  console.log(arrayOfModels); 
  console.log('first item', arrayOfModels[1]); //returns undefined
  const showAllVehicles = (e) => {
    fetch(MODELS_COUNT_URI)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.reduce((total, item) => {
          let arrayNum = +item.model - 1;
          total += `
          <tr>
          <td>Name: ${arrayOfModels[arrayNum]}</td>
          <td>Count: ${item.count}</td>
          </tr>`;
          return (modelsCountOutputElement.innerHTML = total);
        }, '');
      });
  };
  return showAllVehicles();
};
```

Comment: it runs the same when : .then((data) => {
      console.log('this is data', data);
      data.reduce((total, item) => {
        arrayOfModels.push(item.name);
        return arrayOfModels;
      }, '');
      arrayOfModels;

Answer (score 0):

You basically reassigned the variable `total` when you do the line:

```
total = item.name
```

So the variable total is no longer contain/behave as accumulator. Array.Reduce docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

You may need to change that `total` into something else. But I just see that you want to get all car models into an array without any condition, so what you need is more likely `forEach` or `map` instead of `reduce`.

```js
var data =[ {"_id":"611647e62001fe0ff0af0ad6","model":"1","name":"FIAT 500","hour_price":4.2,"__v":0},{"_id":"61165c7e8fecf33528790b45","model":"2","name":"BMW X4","hour_price":6.9,"__v":0}];

var result = data.map(item => item.name);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried doing it like this: " arrayOfModels.push(item.name);
        return arrayOfModels;" but still i get same result. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

agree with Dhana.

and I have a simpler solution

```js
const modelscount = [{"model":"1","count":4},{"model":"2","count":2}] 

const models = [{"_id":"611647e62001fe0ff0af0ad6","model":"1","name":"FIAT 500","hour_price":4.2,"__v":0},{"_id":"61165c7e8fecf33528790b45","model":"2","name":"BMW X4","hour_price":6.9,"__v":0}]

const modalsMap = modelscount.map(({modal, count}) => {
  const findModal = models.find(({modal: modalName}) => modalName === modal)
  return ({count, ...findModal})
})
```